# How to select all URLs inside a text area using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can select all img link as well as PDF link using the following:

```
    $("a[href$='pdf']").append('<img src="pdf.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px;" > ');
    $("a[href$='jpg']").append('<img src="jpg.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px;" > ');
```

Now I have a text area

```
 <textarea id="mytxt" name='post' style='width:100%;height:400px;margin-top:10px;border:solid thin #F1F1F1;line-height:20px;'>

  </textarea>


 $("#mytxt:contains('.jpg')").append('<img src="jpg.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px;" > ');
```

The above selector won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot append a `DOM` element inside a textarea, so the above code can't work

the selector itself `$("#mytxt:contains('.jpg')")` is perfectly working when a `.jpg` occurence is found : see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mqu66/

Comment: ya it's working; 
But here i am trying to replace all img url with img src trag

         <textarea id="mytxt" name='post' style='width:100%;height:400px;margin-top:10px;border:solid thin #F1F1F1;line-height:20px;'>
          txt txt filename.jpg 
          </textarea>

      in the above case it will return hole text. i want to slelect filename.jpg only how can i do the same
   Thanks